# How I can sort liquor collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the collection in Liquor(https://github.com/evilmartians/liquor). I use it like this:

```
{% for dot in: models.dots do: %}
{% end for%}
```

I have attribute `pos_down` in collection `dots`. How i can order this collection?
Something like  this `{% for dot in: models.dots.sort_by('pos_down') do: %}`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use AcctiveRecord, use `order`
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering